# How to color tabu row background in beamer LaTeX

Tags: beamer, color, tabu, colortbl

I am trying to color the background of the third row of this `tabu` environment red:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabu}{XX}
\everyrow{\hline} \hline 
Row 1 & Row 1 \\
Row 2 & Row 2 \\
\rowcolor{red}
Row 3 & Row 3 \\
Row 4 & Row 4 \\
\end{tabu}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `rowcolor` command has no effect, none of the rows has a colored background in the output. I am quite certain this used to work at some point (possibly in the distant past), but I am aware that `colortbl` may (now) be incompatible with `tabu`. I have also tried to use the `\taburowcolors` command instead with no success.

> What is the recommended way to color a single row in a `tabu` environment inside a `beamer` document?

*Note:* I am compiling with XeLaTeX in case this makes a difference.

Comment: \rowcolor is currently broken. Read the readme here and check the issues. https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu

Comment: Thanks a lot @UlrikeFischer. Since this isn't urgent, I might downgrade and watch the issue tracker closely.

Comment: I would simply not use tabu. No tabular in a presentation can be so complicated that you need it.

Comment: If you're using `tabu` just for the `\everyrow` things, I can post some code which should enable you to use something similar in normal `tabular` and `tabularx` tables, too.

Comment: @Skillmon that would indeed be very interesting, thank you!

Comment: To explain: The tabular should indeed not be complicated, but I am creating a template and the user of this template should not be required to insert the horizontal lines manually.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain the problem would be that the code would either require a dedicated environment (and would then be hard to do for `tabularx`), or would affect every `tabular` and `array`. Is that ok? Which seems favourable?

Comment: @Skillmon A dedicated environment is fine, and I think you can use `\tabularx{\texwitdh}{#1}` and `\endtabularx` in `newenvironment`. If that's a showstopper, affecting every tabular and array may also be ok, the only possible conflict would be with code listings, but it would give me something to start. I am grateful for anything =)

Answer (score 4):

In the comments you indicate that you are using tabu to inject a \hline after every row. This could be done also like this (if the optional argument of \ is needed some adjustments must be added):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand\tabnewlinewithhline{\tabularnewline\hline}
\newcommand\tabaddhline{\let\\\tabnewlinewithhline}
\newcolumntype\ccwithhline{c>{\tabaddhline}c}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{\ccwithhline}
\hline
Row 1 & Row 1 \\
Row 2 & Row 2 \\
\rowcolor{red}
Row 3 & Row 3 \\
Row 4 & Row 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following defines two environments, a `mytabular` (which is like `tabular`) and a `mytabularx` (which is like `tabularx`) environment, that do put a `\hline` in between each line and two `\hline`s at the top and the bottom of the environments. It does so by locally patching some internals of the `array` package. Any nested `tabular` or `array` environment should not contain those `\hline`s, which is desirable to create some special alignments (e.g. using `\makecell` needs this). The last row doesn't need to be terminated by `\\` (which is responsible for much of the needed code) in both environments.

The mechanism should work, but if anybody finds bugs, please report them. Also if anybody thinks the mechanism is too clumsy, please feel free to leave comments and suggest something better (I know of `\everycr` but for unknown to me reasons I refrain from using it, so that could be a viable alternative to patching `array`'s `\\`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mypatchcmd[3]%>>>
  {%
    \patchcmd#1{#2}{#3}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching \string#1\space failed}{}{}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\mypretocmd[2]%>>>
  {%
    \pretocmd#1{#2}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching \string#1\space failed}{}{}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\myapptocmd[2]%>>>
  {%
    \apptocmd#1{#2}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching \string#1\space failed}{}{}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand*\unpatch@array%>>>
  {%
    \let \@@array      \@@array@original
    \let \@arraycr     \@arraycr@original
    \let \@xarraycr    \@xarraycr@original
    \let \@xargarraycr \@xargarraycr@original
    \let \@yargarraycr \@yargarraycr@original
    \let \tabular      \tabular@original
    \let \endtabular   \endtabular@original
    \let \array        \array@original
    \let \endarray     \endarray@original
  }%<<<
\newcommand*\patch@array%>>>
  {%
    \mypretocmd\tabular{\unpatch@array}%
    \mypretocmd\array{\unpatch@array}%
    \myapptocmd\@yargarraycr{\my@hline}%
    \mypatchcmd\@xarraycr{\cr}{\cr\my@hline}%
    \mypatchcmd\@xargarraycr{\cr}{\cr\my@hline}%
    \myapptocmd\@@array{\hline\hline}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand*\backup@array%>>>
  {%
    \let \@@array@original      \@@array
    \let \@arraycr@original     \@arraycr
    \let \@xarraycr@original    \@xarraycr
    \let \@xargarraycr@original \@xargarraycr
    \let \@yargarraycr@original \@yargarraycr
    \let \tabular@original      \tabular
    \let \endtabular@original   \endtabular
    \let \array@original        \array
    \let \endarray@original     \endarray
  }%<<<
\newenvironment{mytabular}[2][c]%>>>
  {%>>>
    \backup@array
    \patch@array
    \begin{tabular@original}[#1]{#2}%
  }%<<<
  {%>>>
    \crcr
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabular@original}%
  }%<<<
%<<<
\newcommand\my@hline%>>>
  {%
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \futurelet\reserved@a\my@xhline
  }%<<<
\newcommand\my@xhline%>>>
  {%
    \ifx\reserved@a\end
      \expandafter\my@yhline
    \else
      \hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth
      \ifx\reserved@a\hline
        \vskip\doublerulesep
      \fi
      \expandafter\my@xhline@fin
    \fi
  }%<<<
\newcommand*\my@xhline@fin%>>>
  {%
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\my@yhline[2]%>>>
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\tmpa{#2}%
    \def\tmpb{mytabular}%
    \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \ifx\tmpa\tmpb
    \else
      \hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth
    \fi
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \end{#2}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\mytabularx@expandhelper[2]%>>>
  {%
    #2#1%
  }%<<<
\NewEnviron{mytabularx}%>>>
  {%
    \backup@array
    \patch@array
    \edef\BODY{\expandafter\mytabularx@striplast\expandafter{\BODY}}%
    \expandafter\mytabularx@expandhelper\expandafter{\BODY}{\begin{tabularx}}%
    \crcr
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\myifempty[1]%>>>
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }%<<<
\newcommand\myifnobbackslash[1]%>>>
  {%
    \myifbbackslash@#1\\\endmyifbbackslash@
  }%<<<
\def\myifbbackslash@#1\\#2\endmyifbbackslash@%>>>
  {%
    \myifempty{#2}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\mytabularx@striplast[1]%>>>
  {%
    \myifnobbackslash{#1}
      {%
        \unexpanded{#1}%
      }
      {%
        \mytabularx@striplast@#1\endmytabularx@striplast
      }%
  }%<<<
\def\mytabularx@striplast@#1\\#2\endmytabularx@striplast%>>>
  {%
    \myifempty{#2}
      {%
        \unexpanded{#1}%
      }%
      {%
        \unexpanded{#1\\}%
        \mytabularx@striplast{#2}%
      }%
  }%<<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{mytabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
  Row 1 & Row 1 \\
  Row 2 & Row 2 \\
  \rowcolor{red}
  Row 3 & Row 3 \\
  Row 4 & Row 4 \\
\end{mytabularx}

\bigskip
\begin{mytabular}{ll}
  a & b\\
  c & d\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{ab}\\
  e & f\\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}a\\b\end{tabular} & cd \\
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sincere compliments.